# Conformity issue arises when using interfaces with function pointers

Tags: pointers, interface, fortran, pass-by-reference

I am starting this thread to ask for help solve a problem that might come from my wrong specification of a function interface, but I don't know how to fix it.

The error message I encountered is short and simply says, "Illegal number or type of arguments to lnsrch - arguments of fmin and func do not agree."

The definition of `LNSRCH`, `FMIN`, and `FUNC` will be clear in the content below.

The original program code is trimmed to illustrate my intention as shown below. It consists of three parts: a main program unit called `MAIN`, a module named `MODEL`, and a module named `NEWTON`). You should be able to reproduce the error message just using the following single .f90 format file: [link](http://goo.gl/f4fMd)

Module `MODEL` just defines a simple equations system in two variables---y(1)=x(1); y(2)=x(2) ---in the subprogram `FUNC_SYSTEM1`. Module `MODEL` also contains an abstract interface for future extension so that I can simply make the pointer `FUNCV` to reference any other equation system of the same kind as the current example equation system `FUNC_SYSTEM1`, with the exception only in the number of variables of the equation system.

```
MODULE model                                                             
    IMPLICIT NONE                            
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: fmin_fvecp
    ABSTRACT INTERFACE                              
        FUNCTION function_system_template(x) RESULT(y)     
        REAL, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: x     
        REAL, DIMENSION(SIZE(x)) :: y           
        END FUNCTION                                
    END INTERFACE                                   
    PROCEDURE(function_system_template), POINTER :: funcv  
CONTAINS                                                          
    FUNCTION func_system1(x) Result(y)              
    IMPLICIT NONE                             
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: x   
    REAL, DIMENSION(size(x)) :: y                            
    y(1)=x(1)      
    y(2)=x(2)      
    END FUNCTION func_system1                           
END MODULE model
```

Module `NEWTON` defines the relationship among three subprograms that are key to the program's computing: `BROYDEN` will call `FMIN` to get the sum of squares of x(1) and x(2); simultaneously, in `FMIN`, the vector of x(1) and x(2) is assigned to an array pointer called `FMIN_FVECP`. This array pointer is to be used to do some side calculation in the function `LNSRCH`.

```
MODULE newton 
    USE model
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: fmin_fvecp
CONTAINS
    SUBROUTINE broyden(x,fmin_fvecp,funcv)           
        IMPLICIT NONE
        REAL, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: x
        REAL, DIMENSION(size(x)), TARGET :: y
        REAL, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: fmin_fvecp
        PROCEDURE(function_system_template), POINTER :: funcv
        fmin_fvecp=>y
        print*,fmin(x,fmin_fvecp,funcv)        ! Get the sum of squares
        print*,fmin_fvecp                      ! Show the vector x(1) and x(2)
        print*,lnsrch(x,fmin,fmin_fvecp,funcv) ! Show the figure calculated in LNSRCH
    END SUBROUTINE broyden

    FUNCTION fmin(x,fmin_fvecp,funcv) RESULT(y)
        IMPLICIT NONE
        REAL, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: x
        REAL, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: fmin_fvecp
        PROCEDURE(function_system_template), POINTER :: funcv
        REAL :: y
        fmin_fvecp=funcv(x)                    ! The value of FMIN_FVECP is assigend
        fmin=dot_product(fmin_fvecp,fmin_fvecp)! when FMIN is called by BROYDEN
    END FUNCTION fmin    

    FUNCTION lnsrch(x,func,a_fvecp,b_funcv) RESULT(y)
        IMPLICIT NONE
        REAL, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: x
        REAL, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: a_fvecp 
        PROCEDURE(function_system_template), POINTER :: b_funcv 
        INTERFACE                              
            FUNCTION func(x,fvecp,funcp) 
            IMPORT :: function_system_template  
            IMPLICIT NONE
            REAL, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: x
            REAL :: func
            REAL, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: fvecp 
            PROCEDURE(function_system_template), POINTER :: funcp 
            END FUNCTION                                
        END INTERFACE
        REAL, DIMENSION(SIZE(x)) :: y
        y=x+a_fvecp+b_funcv(x)+1000.
        END FUNCTION lnsrch
    END MODULE newton
```

The main program unit is defined as follows:

```
PROGRAM main
    USE model                            
    USE newton                           
    IMPLICIT NONE  
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), allocatable :: x
    allocate(x(2))
    x=[1.,2.]                         ! The input arguments to be passed into 
    funcv=>func_system1               ! the equation system, FUNC_SYSTEM1.
    call broyden(x,fmin_fvecp,funcv)  ! Call BROYDEN to do the subsequent calcualtion
    deallocate(x)    
END PROGRAM main
```

Sorry for the lengthy post. Thanks for the time reading through my question. Looking forward to any input for working around the error message. Thanks.

Lee

Comment: You declare `fmin_fvecp1` in both modules, which is a conflict since both are used in the program.  You have `fmin=..` in `function fmin`, but not `y=...`, which is a problem since you have declared `result (y)`.

Comment: @M.S.B.: That's a mistake coming from copying and pasting from my program code of different versions. Thank you for pointing it out. After removing the redundant declaration of 'FMIN_FVECP' from module 'NEWTON', the same error message still shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the conflicting use of fmin_fvecp1 mentioned in the comments (which I would expect an explicit compiler error for, note the dummy argument declarations of the same name hide the module variable in the relevant module procedures in module `newton`), note that interface bodies do not automatically inherit via host association the entities defined in their hosts scoping unit, unless an IMPORT statement brings that entity into the scope of the interface block.

Consequently the symbol `function_system_template` in the interface block for the `func` dummy argument in `lnsrch` is not the same thing as that symbol outside of the interface block - consequently the actual and dummy argument procedures do not have the same characteristics.  The lack of a declaration for the symbol inside the interface block is a constraint violation - I would have expected a reasonably specific error from the compiler for this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I use the IMPORT statement in the interface bloack for the `FUNC` dummy argument in `LNSRCH`, and still get the same error message. May I ask if you could spot any further mistake? It is weird to me that the conflict message keeps showing up. Thanks.

Comment: My program added with the IMPORT statement can be downloaded from this [link](http://goo.gl/f4fMd). This is a single .f90 format file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code shown in the content below is the workaround I finally got: I create additional abstract interface and have all subprograms pooled into one single module. Subroutines `BROYDEN`, `FMIN`, and `LNSRCH` are renamed as `MajorSolver`, `MiddleFunction`, and `AssistantSolver`. In the main program unit, three experiments are conducted and their results are shown. The common machinery behind each experiment works as what follows: a equations system is chosen and passed into `MajorSolver`; in the meantime, an array pointer is assumed. The array pointer along with a subprogram pointer that references  `MiddleFunction` are passed into function `AssistantSolver` to compute the sum of squares of the elements in the input argument `x`. In the end, `MajorSolver` returns, for the given input vector `x`, the proportion of square of respective entry in the sum of squares.

```
MODULE model                                                             
IMPLICIT NONE                            
REAL, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: fvec1p, fvec2p           ! <<Note1>>           
ABSTRACT INTERFACE                                      ! <<Note1>> !
    FUNCTION functions_system(x) RESULT(y)              !           !
    IMPLICIT NONE                                       !           !
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: x                 !           !
    REAL, DIMENSION(SIZE(x)) :: y                       !           !
    END FUNCTION                                        !           !
END INTERFACE                                           !           !

ABSTRACT INTERFACE                                      ! <<Note2>> 
    FUNCTION middle_function_template(x,fvec_p,proc_p) RESULT(y)  
    IMPLICIT NONE                                       !
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: x                 !
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: fvec_p               !
    PROCEDURE(functions_system), POINTER :: proc_p      !
    REAL :: y                                           !
    END FUNCTION                                        !
END INTERFACE                                           !

PROCEDURE(functions_system), POINTER :: proc1p, proc2p  ! <<Note1>>   
CONTAINS                                                          
FUNCTION func_system1(x) RESULT(y)                      ! Equation system             
    IMPLICIT NONE                                       ! in two variables     
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: x   
    REAL, DIMENSION(size(x)) :: y                            
    y(1)=x(1)                                        
    y(2)=x(2)                                  
END FUNCTION func_system1

FUNCTION func_system2(x) RESULT(y)                      ! Equation system
    IMPLICIT NONE                                       ! in three variables  
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: x
    REAL, DIMENSION(size(x)) :: y
    y(1)=x(1)*10.
    y(2)=x(2)*10.
    y(3)=x(3)*10.
END FUNCTION func_system2

FUNCTION func_system3(x) RESULT(y)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: x 
    REAL, DIMENSION(SIZE(x)) :: y
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: ans2
    proc2p=>func_system1                                ! 
    allocate(ans2(2))                                   ! <<Note2>>
    call MajorSolver(ans2,x(1:2),fvec2p,proc2p)         !
    y(1)=ans2(1)
    y(2)=ans2(2)
    y(3)=0.
    deallocate(ans2)
END FUNCTION func_system3

SUBROUTINE MajorSolver(ans,x,fvec_p,proc_p)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: ans
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: x
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: fvec_p
    PROCEDURE(functions_system), POINTER :: proc_p
    PROCEDURE(middle_function_template), POINTER :: proc3p
    REAL, DIMENSION(SIZE(x)), TARGET :: y
    REAL :: z
    fvec_p=>y                                           ! pointer initialization <<Note1>>
    proc3p=>MiddleFunction                              ! <<Note2>>
    z=AssistantSolver(x,proc3p,fvec_p,proc_p) 
    ans=fvec_p**2/z          
END SUBROUTINE MajorSolver

FUNCTION MiddleFunction(x,fvec_p,proc_p)                ! <<Note2>> This function returns something
    IMPLICIT NONE                                       ! back to MajorSolver. In this    
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: x                 ! case, it computes the inner product.
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: fvec_p               ! 
    PROCEDURE(functions_system), POINTER :: proc_p
    REAL :: MiddleFunction
    fvec_p=proc_p(x)
    MiddleFunction=dot_product(fvec_p,fvec_p)
END FUNCTION

FUNCTION AssistantSolver(x,func,fvec_p,proc_p)          ! <<Note2>> 
    IMPLICIT NONE                                       ! 
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: x                 ! 
    procedure(middle_function_template), pointer :: func! 
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: fvec_p               !  
    PROCEDURE(functions_system), POINTER :: proc_p      ! 
    REAL :: AssistantSolver                             ! 
    AssistantSolver=func(x,fvec_p,proc_p)               ! 
END FUNCTION AssistantSolver                            ! 
END MODULE model

PROGRAM main
USE model
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: ans
REAL :: data2(2), data3(3)
data2=[1.,2.]
proc1p=>func_system1
allocate(ans(size(data2)))
call MajorSolver(ans,data2,fvec1p,proc1p)
write(*,'(a,2(f7.3))'),'Equations system 1: Ans= ',ans
nullify(ans)

data3=[1.,2.,3.]
proc1p=>func_system2
allocate(ans(size(data3)))
call MajorSolver(ans,data3,fvec1p,proc1p)
write(*,'(a,3(f7.3))'),'Equations system 2: Ans= ',ans
nullify(ans,proc1p)

data3=[1.,2.,3.]
proc1p=>func_system3
allocate(ans(size(data3)))                              ! 
call MajorSolver(ans,data3,fvec1p,proc1p)               ! <<Note1>>
write(*,'(a,3(f7.3))'),'Equations system 3: Ans= ',ans  ! 
! The answer is 0.059 0.941 0.000
! Because in system 3 we calculate system 1 first, the 3rd entry of 
! data3 will be ignored before passed into system 1. The result is
! [0.200 0.800] as we already know in system 1.
! Then this vector will be passed into MajorSolver again. So, 
! the answer is [0.059 0.941] = [0.2**2/(0.2**2+0.8**2) 0.8**2/(0.2**2+0.8**2)]

END PROGRAM main
```

The outcome is

```
Equations system 1: Ans=   0.200  0.800
Equations system 2: Ans=   0.071  0.286  0.643
Equations system 3: Ans=   0.059  0.941  0.000
Press any key to continue . . .
```